# Is there a way to populate a link's title in the utm parameters? Similar to %%linkname%% which populates a link's alias

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

We have Web Analytics Connector (WAC) set up in Salesforce Content Builder. In the email message Properties tab, there are slots to input utm parameters which will append to the end of all links. They are called `__AdditionalEmailAttribute1`, `__AdditionalEmailAttribute2`, etc...

I read you can put `%%linkname%%` in one of these slots to populate a link's alias. Is there a similar string to populate a link's title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in pure `%%` `%%` without any `[ ]` or `=` are called personalization strings and are documented here:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm

(at least for emails, this is the complete list to my knowledge. Cloudpages have at least one more called tabid).

There is no personalization string for the link title. The way you'd usually approach this is by setting an AMPScript variable yourself and then probably work with a data extension for content and use lookup function(s). https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/

```
%%[

SET @myLinkTitle = "this goes into the title"
SET @myDisplayText = "I want to read this"
]%%
<a href="https://www.google.com" alias="whatever" title="%%=v(@myLinkTitle)=%%">%%=v(@myDisplayText)=%%</a>
```